# Getting ibid for numeric citations from biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing

I would like to cite ibid when the same citation is used in succession.

So, instead of it reading Apple is this [1]. This is a pear [1].
It would be Apple is this [1]. This is a pear [ibid].
However, I have not found how to do this with the numeric style. Using `authoryear` also just printed the whole reference. How can I get the numeric citations with ibid?

My code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside, 11pt, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{palatino}
\setlength{\parindent}{2.5em}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style= numeric-comp, ibidpage=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[inner=2.5cm,outer=2.5cm,  tmargin=2.5cm, bmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{color}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
```

Example text: 
Coding capacity is considered to surpass that of the human genome `\cite{Vipperla2012}`. The specific taxa associated with a given species have the power to influence the host’s health `\cite{Vipperla2012}`.

Comment: This is not really related to the `memoir` class as all your citations come from `biblatex`. BTW: you are much more likely to get help if you take the time to provide a fully compilable minimal example. In this case I'll have to provide a lot of extra time to test your example.

Comment: That is a very unusual choice. Do you insist on taking `numeric-comp` as base or would you be OK with `numeric` as well?

Comment: `numeric`would be fine as well

Comment: OK, I think I can make something work with `numeric-comp`, but it may have rough edges.

Comment: Note that for future reference what you have shown us there still is not an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). If you need an example, I consider the full code at the end of my answer fairly MWE-y.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard numeric styles don't come with an `-ibid` version, so we will have to build our own. Note that the reason why those styles don't exist is that they are highly unusual, with numeric citations repeating the citation usually is shorter than "ibid." (which I believe only serves the purpose of not cluttering the text by repeating long citation labels over and over again).

Anyhow for the `numeric-comp` style, we just insert an `ibid`-test into `cite:comp` and define the necessary macros

```
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite:comp}{%
  \addtocounter{cbx@tempcntb}{1}%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\ifbool{bbx:subentry}
          {\iffieldundef{entrysetcount}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:comp:comp}}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:comp:inset}}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:comp:comp}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:comp:shand}}}

\providecommand*{\mkibid}[1]{#1}
\newbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}}
\makeatother
```

In order for this to work you need to load `biblatex` with the `ibidtracker=constrict` option (the option `ibidpage` is not recognised by `numeric`-like styles and will throw an error).

Then the full MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp, backend=biber, ibidtracker=constrict]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite:comp}{%
  \addtocounter{cbx@tempcntb}{1}%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\ifbool{bbx:subentry}
          {\iffieldundef{entrysetcount}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:comp:comp}}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:comp:inset}}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:comp:comp}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:comp:shand}}}

\providecommand*{\mkibid}[1]{#1}
\newbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
  \cite{sigfridsson} and \cite{sigfridsson} and \cite{worman} and \cite{sigfridsson}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

> [1] and [ibid.] and [2] and [1]

Comment: Where do I enter `cite:comp` ?

Comment: @user4476006 Sorry, I don't understand. Just copy the suggested first code block into your preamble (after you load `biblatex`) and you should be good to go (compare what I did in the full example at the end).

Comment: I see, thanks! I thought I had to put both code blocks. Its working now - much appreciated!

Comment: Is there a way to remove the dot from the ibid reference? So its not `[ibid.]` but `[ibid]`

Comment: @user4476006 The dot is of course to be expected, "ibid." is an abbreviation after all. If you write in English (or British/American/...) try `\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{ibidem = {ibid}}`.