# Getting ibid for apa-style citations from biblatex

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

**Goal:** I want to cite using the biblatex-apa style, with the extension that (ibid.) is added, when the same source is quoted multiple times.

---

**Note:** This is a follow-up question to [Getting ibid for numeric citations from biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/328230/166624)

Also, I know that ibidem is explicitly **not** a part of the APA citation style and by some is even considered as old-fashioned or outdated, but every institution has their own requirements, and since biblatex-apa meets my requirements in every other aspect, I would like to add this little extension to it instead of using another style.

In the thread linked above, they do something similar with the numeric-comp-style, but copying the suggested code to my preamble does not help in my case. Since I am not experienced enough for this kind of "LaTeX Hacking", ***how would an equivalent code as the one suggested in the [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328230/getting-ibid-for-numeric-citations-from-biblatex) above look for biblatex-apa?***

My minimal working document looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

% Bibliography entries:
\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
@booklet{one,
author = {Author One},
title = {Testtitle 1.},
date = {2018},
}
@booklet{two,
author = {Author Two},
title = {Testtitle 2.},
date = {2018},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}   
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,sortlocale=de_DE]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}

\begin{document}
First citation should be normal \parencite{one}, second time with ibidem 
\parencite{one}, but after a second citation \parencite{two} it should 
appear as usual \parencite{one}.    
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**This is what I get:**

[image: Document without ibidem]

**...and this is what i would like to get:**

[image: Document with ibidem]

*Note that (ebd.) ist just the german version of (ibid.).*

Thank you a lot for any help and suggestions. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This needs a bit of code, but the actual changes to the original defintions from `.cbx` are not that big.

First we need to define a macro to print the ibidem, `cite:ibid` (copied from `authoryear-ibid.cbx`). We also request the ibidem tracker with `ibidtracker=constrict` and page tracking (to avoid a "ibid." at the beginning of a page) with `pagetracker`.

Then it is just a matter of inserting the conditional `\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}` in the right place in the `cite` and `textcite` macros and adding a call to `cite:ibid`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, pagetracker, ibidtracker=constrict]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\mkibid}[1]{#1}

\newbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
    {\iffieldequals{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}
     % Multiple cites in one command
      {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
       \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}}%
     % Single cite
      {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{patent}}
     % No author/editor
         {\usebibmacro{cite:noname}%
          \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
          \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}%
          \savefield{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}}
     % Normal cite
        {\ifnameundef{shortauthor}
           {\printnames[labelname][-\value{listtotal}]{labelname}}%
           {\cbx@apa@ifnamesaved
             {\printnames{shortauthor}}
             {\printnames[labelname][-\value{listtotal}]{author}%
              \addspace\printnames[sabrackets]{shortauthor}}}%
         \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
         \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}%
         \savefield{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}}%
   \setunit{\multicitedelim}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \iffieldequals{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}
   % Compact cite - more than one thing for same author
    {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}}
   % New cite
    {%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}
      {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
      {}%
      \setunit{\compcitedelim}%
      \ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{patent}}
    % No author/editor or patent
       {\iffieldundef{shorthand}%
    % Cite using title
         {\usebibmacro{cite:noname}%
          \setunit{\ifbool{cbx:np}%
                   {\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
                   {\global\booltrue{cbx:parens}\addspace\bibopenparen}}%
          \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}}
    % Cite using shorthand
         {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    % Normal cite with author/editor
    % Normal full cite
       {\ifnameundef{shortauthor}%
    % Normal full cite
         {\printnames[labelname][-\value{listtotal}]{labelname}}
    % Cite using short author
         {\cbx@apa@ifnamesaved
           {\printnames{shortauthor}}
           {\printnames[labelname][-\value{listtotal}]{author}}}%
    % Year
        \setunit{\ifbool{cbx:np}
                  {\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}
                  {\global\booltrue{cbx:parens}\addspace\bibopenparen}}%
    % Put the shortauthor inside the year brackets if necessary
        \ifnameundef{shortauthor}
         {}
         {\cbx@apa@ifnamesaved
           {}
           {\printnames{shortauthor}\setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}}%
    % Actual year printing
        \ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}}%
    % Save name hash for checks later
        \savefield{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
First citation should be normal \parencite{sigfridsson}, second time with ibidem
\parencite{sigfridsson}, but after a second citation \parencite{geer} it should
appear as usual \parencite{sigfridsson}.

\cite{nussbaum}

First citation should be normal \textcite{sigfridsson}, second time with ibidem
\textcite{sigfridsson}, but after a second citation \textcite{geer} it should
appear as usual \textcite{sigfridsson}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: First citation should be normal (Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998), second time with ibidem (ebd.), but after a second citation (Geer, 1985) it should appear as usual (Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998). Nussbaum, 1978 First citation should be normal Sigfridsson und Ryde (1998), second time with ibidem Sigfridsson und Ryde (ebd.), but after a second citation Geer (1985) it should appear as usual Sigfridsson und Ryde (1998).]

Comment: Very nice - thank you for the great explanation and answer! :)

Comment: Maybe one additional question: based on the code in your answer I guess it might be easy to deactivate this behaviour for a single quote? E.g. if you have two chapters, and the document structure requires the same citation in the end of the last and in the beginning of the new chapter - would it be possible to "supress" this for a single citation? Maybe by setting a certain parameter before and after the quote?

Comment: @Pidrittel If the chapter starts on a new page the page tracking already takes care of that. You can use the command `\citereset` to reset ibidem tracking (and a bit more if applicable) at a certain point. With the `citereset` option (p. 52 of the documentation) you can automatically execute that command at the beginning of a `\chapter` or `\section`. The `biblatex-apa` feature to show the full list of authors at a first citation can be reset with `\citeresetapa`, but there is no option to have this applied automatically at each section.

Comment: @ moewe: This works, too. You are a god. Highly appreciated! :)

Comment: I found another case which I want to avoid: citations in Figures should never be shorted by `ebd.` Is there a way to check if the citations is inside a figure caption?

Comment: @Pidrittel The "ibid" function is normally turned off in floats because a "ibid." could be potentially confusing. Do you use a non-floating caption? Anyway, I think you should ask a new question about that (ideally with a short MWE, if the code here is not the problem try using `authoryear-ibid` as a basis and not all the modifications here).

Comment: It appears in captions of floating figures, in which I cite using the `\citep{}` command. It seems not to be turned off when I use the Code you posted above.

Comment: @Pidrittel The code I posted should not influence whether or not "ibid" tracking is turned on or off in floats. (i) Can you reproduce a similar problem when you just use the standard style `style=authoryear-ibid` instead of the complicated code? (ii) Please ask a new question with a short example document ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/)) that shows the issue, include a screenshot of the output you get and explain what you would like to see instead. If you can reproduce the issue with `style=authoryear-icomp` use that.

Comment: Ok I will do some MWEs and look if I can reproduce, and if so post a new question. :) Thanks.

Comment: @Pidrittel Good. I remember that when you first commented a few days ago I threw together a very small MWE and there the tracking was disabled in floats, so I'm not just asking to annoy you, *this really should not happen and an MWE is the only way to find out if there is a bug and how to fix it*.

Comment: Sorry if it seemed like it, but you certainly do not annoy me. :) I'm glad that you are so active here and that you have such a hiue experience with biblatex. 

Meanwhile I also threw together a MWE, but I wasn't able to recreate the behaviour. Interestingly I still can reproduce it in my main document. I'll try to shrink the main document tomorrow to further locate where the different behaviour of my main and my MWE comes from.

Comment: I have news, but I am not sure if I am supposed to start a new question about this here (but maybe I will). I found the reason for the strange behaviour of the ebd. in captions: 

I used figures with the `[H]` placement character from the `floatrow`(!) - package. Using the standard `float`-package instead fixes the issues. @moewe, can you confirm that ebd. in captions is bugged when using the mentioned settings?

Comment: @Pidrittel Ah yes, just today I learned that `H` makes float environments behave very weirdly. If you need a deeper investigation into this issue, please open a new question.

Comment: Luckily, for my current work, I don't need the `floatrow` package, so I just replaced it with `float` again. It wasn't' the first time it crashed m bibliography either; there was still a workaround sitting in my preamble from an earlier document. :D But I guess, I will open a Question anyways so that a bug might be found & fixed.