# Getting ibid without page numbers for apa-style citations from biblatex

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

As Pidrittel [asked already here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449249/getting-ibid-for-apa-style-citations-from-biblatex) I need ibid in apa-style. The answer by moewe is already close to what I need. Just one additional aspect is missing. When an ibid is used and the citation before quotes the same page, the page shall not be printed.

Comment: The code from the answer throws errors with both a current version of `biblatex-apa` and `biblatex-apa6`. Can you please tell us which `biblatex-apa` version you are using? (Run a simple document using `biblatex-apa` and add `\listfiles` to the top of the document. Then check the `.log` file for the reported package version. Alternatively, you can search through the `.log` file without `\listfiles` and try to hunt down the version.)

Comment: @moewe Do you mean this line? `File: apa.dbx 2020/04/08 v9.9 APA biblatex style data model`

Comment: Yeah, that's the one. I have `2020/05/30 v9.13 APA` I can write an answer, but it will only be tested with that version. I broadly expect things to work, but there could be one or two rough edges we'll have to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to [Getting ibid for apa-style citations from biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/449249/35864) was based on an older version of `biblatex-apa`.

This is the solution from there updated to a current version of `biblatex-apa` (2020/05/30 v9.13) plus the code for the `ibidpage` option, which can be taken directly from `authoryear-ibid.cbx` (basically all the code that involves `loccit` below is code for that option).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, pagetracker, ibidtracker=constrict]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\newbool{cbx:loccit}

\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{ibidpage}[true]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{true}
    {\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{loccittracker=constrict}}
    {\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{loccittracker=false}}}

\providecommand*{\mkibid}[1]{#1}

\newbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}%
  \ifloccit
    {\global\booltrue{cbx:loccit}}
    {}}


\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
    {\iffieldequals{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}
   % Multiple cites in one command
      {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
       \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}}%
   % Single cite
      {\ifnameundef{labelname}
   % No author/editor
        {\usebibmacro{cite:noname}%
          \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
          \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}%
          \savefield{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}}
   % Normal cite
        {\ifnameundef{shortauthor}
          {\printnames{labelname}}%
          {\cbx@apa@ifnamesaved
            {\printnames{shortauthor}}
            {\ifnameundef{groupauthor}
              {\printnames[labelname]{author}}
              {\printnames[labelname]{groupauthor}}%
             \addspace\printnames[sabrackets]{shortauthor}}}%
          \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
         \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}%
         \savefield{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}%
      \setunit{\multicitedelim}}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \global\boolfalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \iffieldequals{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}
% Compact cite - more than one thing for same author
    {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}}
% New cite
    {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
       {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
       {}%
     \setunit{\textcitedelim}%
     \ifnameundef{labelname}
     % No author/editor
       {\iffieldundef{shorthand}%
    % Cite using title
         {\usebibmacro{cite:noname}%
          \setunit{\global\booltrue{cbx:parens}\addspace\bibopenparen}%
          \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}}
    % Cite using shorthand
         {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
  % Normal cite with author/editor
  % Normal full cite
       {\ifnameundef{shortauthor}%
    % Normal full cite
         {\printnames{labelname}}
    % Cite using short author
         {\cbx@apa@ifnamesaved
           {\printnames{shortauthor}}
           {\ifnameundef{groupauthor}
             {\printnames[labelname]{author}}
             {\printnames[labelname]{groupauthor}}}}%
  % Year
        \setunit{\global\booltrue{cbx:parens}\addspace\bibopenparen}%
  % Put the shortauthor inside the year brackets if necessary
        \ifnameundef{shortauthor}
         {}
         {\cbx@apa@ifnamesaved
           {}
           {\printnames{shortauthor}%
            \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}}%
  % Print prenote (belongs to first cite)
        \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
           {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
           {}%
  % Actual year printing
        \ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extradate}}%
  % Save name hash for checks later
        \savefield{fullhash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
    \stepcounter{textcitecount}}}

\letbibmacro{orig:postnote}{postnote}

\renewbibmacro*{postnote}{%
  \ifbool{cbx:loccit}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{orig:postnote}}}
\makeatother

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{ibidpage=true}

\begin{document}
First citation should be normal \parencite{sigfridsson}, second time with ibidem
\parencite{sigfridsson}, but after a second citation \parencite{geer} it should
appear as usual \parencite{sigfridsson}.

\cite{nussbaum}

\autocite[3]{sigfridsson}

\autocite[4]{sigfridsson}

\autocite[4]{sigfridsson}

\cite{nussbaum}

First citation should be normal \textcite{sigfridsson}, second time with ibidem
\textcite{sigfridsson}, but after a second citation \textcite{geer} it should
appear as usual \textcite{sigfridsson}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998, S. 3)//(ebd., S. 4)//(ebd.)]